# credit for vs credit on

Tags: word-usage

As it happens, fertility rate declines in China have been close to what we would expect on the basis of these social influences alone. China often **gets too much credit** from commentators **on** the alleged effectiveness of its harsher interventions, and far too little **for** the positive role of its supportive policies (including its heavy focus on education and health care, from which many other countries can learn).

---

This is the clip of a nytimes article, which made me wonder about the usage of the preposition "on" with the verb phrase "get credit". If the word "credit" is used by the meaning of "praise", shouldn't it get used with the preposition "for"? If the preposition "on" could be used in this piece, how do I feel the difference between "on" and "for" when they are in accordance with this word "credit"?

link : http://www.nytimes.com/2015/11/02/opinion/amartya-sen-womens-progress-outdid-chinas-one-child-policy.html?_r=0

Comment: "To get credit on something" means to borrow money with that something as security.  You get credit *for* praiseworthy deeds.  However, you comment *on* a topic.  I think the attraction of *commentators* to the preposition *on* led the writer to make that choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preposition is one of the trickiest parts of English and its usage is confusing. In your example, you could use "for" and "on" for each of them. More broadly used one is "[for](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/for)" which means:

> Having (the thing mentioned) ***as a reason or cause***

"[On]" has a similar (***not the same***) definition:

> Having (the thing mentioned) ***as a basis***

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

"[On account of](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/on-account-of?q=on+account+of)" is a phrasal preposition which means "because of" and "[on the basis of](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/on-the-basis-of)" means "based on", "because of", "due to", etc.

[Collins Online Dictionary]

Therefore, "on" can be used instead of "for" when a reason/basis follows it. "On' in your sentence means "on account of" or "on the basis of".

You can find some articles using "on" like [this](http://comicbook.com/2015/09/18/bill-finger-to-get-credit-on-gotham-and-batman-v-superman/) which has the same usage as the one in your article.

Note: Newspaper journalists/editors hate "*repetition of the same words*". The writer might have chosen to use "on" in place of "for" to avoid it and using "on" doesn't change the fundamental meaning.

Comment: Thanks to you, my headache has completely gone away!!! Thanks!!!!!!! Your answer is really helpful : )

Comment: @anotherworld Glad that I helped. :)